# Ayuda con ejercicio en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

lo que pasa es que en este ejercicio, tengo que ingresar una hora de entrada a cada consulta especifica (ya sea con un doctor de medicina general, odontologo, dermatologo, etc), luego de eso tengo que sumar los minutos que me demoro en cada consulta y el resultado de esa suma me dará la hora de salida, en este código no entiendo porque lo tengo malo.

Me tira error en la línea del `dtDate=format.parse(edt1.getText());` no reconoce el parse, sale en rojo

Unknown class: 'dtDate',
Cannot resolve symbol 'parse',
Cannot resolve symbol 'getText'

Esos son los 3 errores que salen en dicha línea.

Código completo (MainActivity)

```
    package com.example.asus.example1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText edt1;
EditText edt2;
EditText edt3;
TextView t1;
Button btn1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor1);
        edt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.valor2);
        t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);

        }
   public static java.util.Date minusDate(java.util.Date fch, int minutos){
       Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
       cal.setTimeInMillis(fch.getTime());
       cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutos);
        return new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    }

    DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    java.util.Date dtDate;
    dtDate=format.parse(edt1.getText());




}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @nicolasyo1WWE, el error que comentas se debe a lo que tu método espera y el método `getText()` retorna, si te fijas al entrar al método `edt1.getText()` retorna un objeto tipo `(Editable)` pero lo que el método `format.parse()` espera en su parámetro es un `String`, esto lo probé utilizando el método de conversión `String.valueOf()` de la siguiente manera en el `getText()`, `dtDate=format.parse(String.valueOf(edt1.getText()));` y me funciono el formateo, nose si esto te ayuda en algo.

Comment: @Jorgesys efectivamente puse el punto del mouse para poder visualizar los errores, y dichos errores son los que nombré en la publicación, la respuesta que pusiste anteriormente la eliminaste porque no aparece

Comment: @Nicethunder Me siguen apareciendo los mismos errores :(

Comment: si creo ver el problema  @nicolasyo1WWE esta seccion deberia estar dentro de las llaves de tu oncreate `DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    java.util.Date dtDate;
    dtDate=format.parse(edt1.getText());`

Comment: corta esa seccion y colócalo debajo de `t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);` y aplica el converso que te escribí en el primer comentario

Comment: @Nicethunder Perdona tanta preguntas men, pero ahora me sale el siguiente error al hacer lo que tu me dijiste: Unhandled exception: java.text.ParseException

Comment: si no hay problema para eso es esta comunidad, eso ya seria por el texto que se trata de parsear, si intentaste esto `dtDate=format.parse(String.valueOf(edt1.getText()));` con el siguiente texto "10:50" en tu edittext te deberia aparecer un mensaje agregando el siguiente toast debajo de ese metodo `Toast.makeText(this,dtDate.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` , esto unicamente para ver que esta funcionando el código, esto lo digo por que no se muy bien que intentas lograr con tu código, aunque veo que tiene preguntas que siguen este tema así que me pasare a leerla

Comment: @Nicethunder basicamente intento mostrar la hora de salida, osea que eso se me genere, cuando sume los minutos por cada consulta

Comment: @Nicethunder si conversamos por mensaje, si es que tienes tiempo, así te puedo explicar mas claramente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86566/discussion-between-nicolasyo1wwe-and-nicethunder).